# How to get rusti working?

Tags: rust

I installed Rust 0.6 yesterday. I've read the tutorial and am excited to get coding. I don't see any mention of rusti on my machine as a result of the install. Do I need to download the source and build myself? I'm on a windows machine. Thanks.

Edit: I just found the answer here [on the wiki](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6088?source=cc). So now I guess the question is, has anyone built a binary of rusti for windows they could share?

Comment: In the future, you can answer your own question instead of editing your question to ask a different question. :)

Source: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that but I guess I was cheating a little, hoping someone would read it and help out.

Comment: For the record, I do not know if anyone has built a Windows binary for rusti -- however, the community is very friendly on both the [IRC channel](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust) and the [mailing list](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/rust-dev).

Comment: @MFlamer: check https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/6088 again, that's suggesting it's fixed in 0.7. And again—ask more questions, not less ;-)

Comment: Thanks Chris, just downloaded 0.7.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `rusti` is removed. It is essentially a fork of compiler at this point. And keeping it synchronized with Rust is **really** hard work.

See this discussion for more info:
  - https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Meeting-weekly-2013-10-15.
  - https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/9818